# sticky-top navbar breaks up only in android mobile

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, navbar

we're running tharuvi.com

The sticky-top navbar which has the search box & Menu button, works fine on desktop and iphone devices. In android devices (small size may be) the Menu and Search box breaks up into 2 lines, though I tried reducing the width of search box to accommodate it in one line but that doesnt seem fix the problem.  How can I adjust all that in one single line even on smaller screens.

Im using bootstrap5, jquery.

Codeblock:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md p-0 sticky-top ps-0 bg-body-tertiary " style="background-color:#FAFAFA">
  <div class="container-fluid px-0">
          <!--a class="navbar-brand" href="/market"><i class="fa fa-home" aria-hidden="true"></i></a-->
      <div class="btn-group pe-1">
  <button class="btn btn-success-outline btn-sm dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" data-bs-auto-close="false" aria-expanded="true">
<!--i class="fa fa-bars" aria-hidden="true"></i--> <b>MENU</b>
          </button>
            <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
                {% for obj in categories %}
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="{% url 'st-shoppe-category' obj.storetype.id obj.id %}">{{obj.name}}</a>
                {%endfor%}
                <hr>
                <!--a class="dropdown-item" href="/allproducts">All Products</a-->



                <div class="accordion accordion-flush small small" id="accordionFlushExample">
                    {% for obj in stall %}
  <div class="accordion-item">
    <h2 class="accordion-header" id="flush-headingOne{{forloop.counter}}">
      <button class="accordion-button collapsed" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#flush-collapseOne{{forloop.counter}}" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="flush-collapseOne{{forloop.counter}}">
          {{obj.name}}
      </button>
    </h2>
    <div id="flush-collapseOne{{forloop.counter}}" class="accordion-collapse collapse" aria-labelledby="flush-headingOne{{forloop.counter}}" data-bs-parent="#accordionFlushExample">
      <div class="accordion-body">
          {% for mobj in obj.pdctg_set.all %}
                          <a class="dropdown-item" href="{% url 'st-shoppe-category' mobj.storetype.id mobj.id %}">{{mobj.name}}</a>
          {%endfor%}
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
                    {%endfor%}
</div>




            </div>
        </div>



      <form class="d-flex ps-0 pe-0" method="get" action="{% url 'search-name' %}">
        <input class="form-control reduceboxsize" value="{{ query }}" name="q" type="search" placeholder="Search" id="snametag" aria-label="Search">
          <button class="btn btn-outline-success" name="st" value="{{st.url}}" type="submit">&#x1F50D;</button>
      </form>
    <button class="navbar-toggler btn btn-sm ps-0" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse"  data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
      <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto mb-lg-0">
          <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="/shops">Shops</a>
        </li><li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="/brands">Brand Store</a>
        </li><li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="/types">Kamblu</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="/h/contact_us">Contact us</a>
        </li>

        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#" tabindex="-1" aria-disabled="true">Market</a>
        </li>
      </ul>

    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```